# Cant echo PHP variable inside <script> tags?

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

This is my PHP code. I want error to be displayed using an alert window.

```
 if ($projectid=="")
  {
    $error = 'You must choose a project.
              Click &lsquo;back&rsquo; and try again.';
    include error.html.php';
    exit();
  }
```

This is error.html.php that is supposed to be parsed by the browser

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Script Error</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


    </head>

    <body>

         <script> 
             var error = <?php echo   $error ; ?>;
              window.onload = function(){ alert(error); }
         </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Wahts up with the script tags ? Do they prevent PHP from running ?

Comment: What does the alert show?

Comment: javascript is executed on the client side, and php on the server side and nary the twain shall meet...

Comment: @Katie lol - If the Javascript is inline HTML and not in a JS file then you can use as much PHP as you want in it.

Comment: ` <script>
        alert("this works");   
   </script>`

Comment: @Katie I would prefer people don't try to mix the two either, but PHP can echo javascript that gets executed by the client...

Comment: @asehgal, then either the value of `$error` is `error` or you are missing a `$`.  You just edited your comment, so I don't know what you're doing now.

Comment: @asehgal can you include more code.

Comment: `<script>
        alert("this works");   
   </script>`

Comment: Yes, I ran it just for grins and it <?php echo $error; ?> comes up in the modal, because it is in quotes... didn't play with it further...

Comment: @asehgal Are you sure that $error is defined? Just change out the variable for some phrase and you'll see the PHP works

Comment: it works just with PHP. not with script tags though.

Comment: @asehgal - you can run this code <?php echo "<script>alert({$error})</script>"?>; if $error is defined and that should cause the alert to show the error, but remember, that will get executed on the server side, then the alert will show on the client side...hope that helps!

Comment: @asehgal Try this: `alert(<?php echo '"'.$error.'"'; ?>);`

Comment: Is the php error being generated before the javascript is executed?

Comment: @hopkins-matt Since it's server-side, it's equivalent to typing the phrase out manually in the alert. JS doesn't know the difference.

Comment: @Katie that didnt work.

Comment: @awl19 But JS knows if the alert is empty. If the error is generate via AJAX for example but the alert code is rendered prior, you'll never see the error in the alert.

Comment: @asehgal Yup, trying it out on my system...sorry hang on...

Comment: A lot of people shooting in the dark. PHP can echo into script tags, but there is probably an issue with the PHP. However, we're all looking at the JS.

Comment: @asehgal, see my answer...I forgot the quotes around the $error, the code in my answer is tested, hope that helps!

Comment: I have updated my question to add more details. Sorry for the confusion. Thanks to all for your help and effort. The above solutions did not work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The *real* problem is that this is what your rendered result looks like:

```
var error = You must choose a project.
            Click &lsquo;back&rsquo; and try again.
```

Does that looks like valid JavaScript to you? I think not.

```
var error = <?=json_encode($error);?>;
```

That should result in:

```
var error = "You must choose a project.\r\n                 Click &lsquo;back&rsquo; and try again.";
```

Much better.

Comment: yes I didnt know I needed JSON. thanks ! What is JSON and why is it needed ?

Comment: Technically, you don't. It's just a way of reformatting the string so that JS can understand it. It does things like replace literal newlines with `\n`, so the interpreter can understand that this is all part of one string.
You could also do such things manually, but the JSON formatter is a useful shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `javascript` is run on the client and will run after the page loads and so after the `php` is run on the server.

However, you can do something like the following which allows `php` to set the value of a `javascript` variable when the page loads and then AFTER the page is loaded runs the `javascript` to display the message.

```
<?php 
$error = "test me";
echo "<script>error = '" . $error  . "'</script>";
?>

<script>
var error;
window.onload = function(){
    alert(error);
}

</script>
```

**UPDATE**
Based on your edits, here's an updated answer.
The `echo "<script>error = '" . $error  . "'</script>"` is needed to assign the `$error` to the `javascript` variable when the page is loaded.

```
if ($projectid=="")
  {
    $error = 'You must choose a project.
              Click ‘back’ and try again.';
    echo "<script>error = '" . json_encode($error)  . "'</script>"
    include error.html.php';
    exit();
}
```

And the html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Script Error</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


    </head>

    <body>

         <script> 
             var error;
              window.onload = function(){ alert(error); }
         </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I did incorporate your solution but its not working. I have edited my question to include more details.

Comment: You can't have `php` within `<script>` tags. I will update my answer with how it should look.

Comment: Note that you must use json_encode() if you are including special characters. I have updated the answer so it works. I replaced the special entities with its simple character equivalent

Comment: Great ! that works. I am not familiear with ?JSON. why is that needed ?

Comment: the `json_` functions  are a simple format designed to exchange data between different programming languages. You are sending a value from php to javascript by way of the browser output. When writing a javascript variable declaration e.g. error = 'some message here', 'some message' may have characters that will break the code - e.g. 'mary's shoe'. By using json_encode, you let the function escape all special characters. Take a look at the documentation for the different options you can use. Using this json_encode, you can also pass arrays.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an $error within your PHP, then you can write:

```
<?php
   echo "<html><head></head><body></body>";

   $error = "whoops!"; // just for testing

   echo "<script>\n";
   echo "alert('{$error}')\n";
   echo "</script>\n";

   echo "</html>";
?>
```

and the alert will happen as soon as the page is loaded, tested it on my server.  This is for the situation where the $error is happening on the server side. (By the way, thanks for the fun question this late in my day!)

Comment: I am using PHP 7. It still doesnt work. I am not sure whats happening.

Comment: You also need to ensure that you are generating a proper HTML heading as well, so the browser has context...I ran mine within a full HTML page (this code was at the bottom)

Comment: OK, I edited my answer with the full file that works on my server, just to be sure we are running the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's quite simple.

```
if ($projectid=="")
{
    $error = 'You must choose a project.
              Click &lsquo;back&rsquo; and try again.';
    include 'error.html.php';
    exit();
}
```

`$error` will now contain `You must choose a project. Click &lsquo;Back&rsquo; and try again`. Note, there are no quotes, so then the line

```
var error = <?php echo   $error ; ?>;
```

looks like this in the client:

```
var error = You must choose a project. 
Click &lsquo;Back&rsquo; and try again;
```

Which naturally causes an error as that is not valid javascript. You need to add quotes, either inside the definition of `$error` serverside or outside the PHP -- something along the lines of:

```
$error = '"You must choose a project.
              Click &lsquo;back&rsquo; and try again."';
```

OR

```
var error = '<?php echo   $error ; ?>';
```

as per your preference...

Answer (score 0):

You certainly can use inline php to generate javascript code. They will, of course, be executed in different contexts, Server-Side vs. Client-Side, but that's mostly irrelevant.

However, you have to realize that the two languages aren't communicating as such, but part of the JS is being generated by the output of the PHP. You have to be careful about that output. One of the issues you have is that JS does not support multiline strings, so the value of $error in PHP can't have a newline.

Try this instead:

```
if ($projectid=="")
  {
    $error = 'You must choose a project. Click \"back\" and try again.';
    include 'error.html.php';
    exit();
  }
```

and

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Script Error</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


    </head>

    <body>

         <script> 
             var error = "<?php echo $error ; ?>";
              window.onload = function(){ alert(error); }
         </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

List of fixes:

1. Fixed quotes in the include statement.
2. Added quotes around the inline PHP echo in the JS code.
3. Removed the newline in the $error var so JS gets it all in one line.
4. Removed html quotes and replaced them with escaped regular quotes. Alert boxes don't process those.